# What is the best and cheapest CMS for an E-Commerce site?

Tags: php, wordpress, cms, drupal, ruby-on-rails

My client needs a site customers can use to pay the membership fees and join. It should also track when old members need to pay again. There are some members that will not want to pay online and they want to be able to use the site to manage all payments. The CMS must be cheap to host online, potentially with something like GitHub/Heroku.

I am experienced with PHP and RoR. I am using a CMS so once I am done with this project it is easy for them to update.

After reading through different posts I think WordPress with an e-commerce Plugin may be the right solution. Spree and WebGUI also looks promising. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Best? or cheapest? It's usually hard to get both.

Comment: Best free and open source solution with a cheap payment method (paypal?). Do these solutions make it easy to manage all payments and not just online payments? They have some clients who are paying monthly and some all at once.

Answer (score 2):

I've played with Magento, which is one of the more popular open-source solutions out there. I wasn't too keen on the structure of the file system, for me it wasn't very intuitive to dive in and figure out how to customize templates. I personally had a better experience building an eCommerce site using [OpenCart](http://www.opencart.com/). It has an active user forum for getting answers. It was easier for me to jump in to the code and figure out how to make changes. To each their own though...

Answer (score 1):

Joomla might be worth a look.  They have an excellent Social Community plugin that allows for paid membership:
http://www.joomlapolis.com/

Some features of Joomlapolis as shown on their webpage:
    * Add member subscriptions to your community
    * Allow paid or free memberships
    * Subscribers pay you
    * Sell products and services
    * Collect donations
    * Control access to content

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely love [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) for cheap quick E-commerce websites. I put together a website on it last year for a swimwear company. Here's a link to the site I built on it for comparison in case you want a real word example to see versus the demo they have on their website:
http://www.swankini.com/

It also has plenty of developer support, plugins, and templates out there. It's targeted more towards an e-commerce website than a blog so it won't have as nice blog functionality as wordpress out of the box.

Comment: Magento is a resource hog. Too complex for a quick e-commerce website.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested opencart is one of the good ecommerce CMS developed using php and Mysql.
Simple MVC structure code base and also simple admin interface for end users.